# React: how can I force state to update in a functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This function component has a template method that calls `onChangeHandler`, which accepts a `select` value and updates `state`. The problem is, `state` does not update until after the render method is called a second time, which means the value of selected option is one step ahead of the `state` value of `selectedRouteName`.

I know there are lifecycle methods in class components that I could use to force a `state` update, but I would like to keep this a function component, if possible.

As noted in the code, the logged state of `selectedRouteDirection` is one value behind the selected option. How can I force the `state` to update to the correct value in a functional component?

This question is not the same as similarly named question because my question asks about the actual implementation in my use case, not whether it is possible.

```
import React, { useState, Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';

const parser = require('xml-js');

const RouteSelect = props => {
    const { routes } = props;

    const [selectedRouteName, setRouteName] = useState('');
    const [selectedRouteDirection, setRouteDirection] = useState('');

    //console.log(routes);

    const onChangeHandler = event => {

        setRouteName({ name: event.target.value });

        if(selectedRouteName.name) {
            getRouteDirection();
        }
    }
/*
    useEffect(() => {
        if(selectedRouteName) {
            getRouteDirection();
        }
    }); */

    const getRouteDirection = () => {

        const filteredRoute = routes.filter(route => route.Description._text === selectedRouteName.name);
        const num = filteredRoute[0].Route._text;

        let directions = [];
        fetch(`https://svc.metrotransit.org/NexTrip/Directions/${num}`)
            .then(response => { 
                return response.text();
            }).then(response => {
                return JSON.parse(parser.xml2json(response, {compact: true, spaces: 4}));
            }).then(response => {
                directions = response.ArrayOfTextValuePair.TextValuePair;
                // console.log(directions);
                setRouteDirection(directions);    
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });

            console.log(selectedRouteDirection); // This logged state is one value behind the selected option
    }

    const routeOptions = routes.map(route => <option key={route.Route._text}>{route.Description._text}</option>);

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <select onChange={onChangeHandler}>
                {routeOptions}
            </select>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default RouteSelect;
```

Comment: Using `useEffect()` should lead to the right direction

Comment: jcal can you please help me understand how I would implement `useEffect()`?  What call would go inside it, and how/when would I call it? If you could provide this in an answer I would be able to accept and give you credit. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually.. even though I still think effects are the right way to go.. your `console.log` is in the wrong place.. `fetch` is asynchronous and your `console.log` is right after the `fetch` instruction.

As @Bernardo states.. setState is also asynchronous
so at the time when your calling `getRouteDirection();`, `selectedRouteName` might still have the previous state.

So to make `getRouteDirection();` trigger after the state was set.
You can use the effect and pass `selectedRouteName` as second parameter (Which is actually an optimization, so the effect only triggers if `selectedRouteName` has changed)

So this should do the trick:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  getRouteDirection();
}, [selectedRouteName]);
```

But tbh.. if you can provide a Stackblitz or similar, where you can reproduce the problem. We can definitely help you better.

Comment: `console.log()` is not inside of fetch. Regardless, making the change to where the console logs, does not change the problem. The state value is still one step behind. Perhaps useEffect is better? Would you be willing to show me your idea?

Answer (score 0):

setState is **asynchronous!** Many times React will look like it changes the state of your component in a synchronous way, but is not that way.